# Extjs move toolbar components to next line when they are moving out of screens

Tags: extjs, extjs3

2 . I am using a toolbar which contains 6 components, which are displaying horizontally on toolbar. When am using my application in smaller screens(mobile), right-sided 2 to 3 components of toolbar are moving out of screen or browser. How can I make that these components should be moved to the next line of same toolbar, when am accessing my application in smaller screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround for this, *only* if you knew how many toolbar items you could fit on a row, is to create two toolbars with this many items and have them sit alongside each other in an hbox layout. Then use the responsiveConfig to switch to a vbox layout at a narrower width, which will shift the second toolbar below the other.

Here's a quick Fiddle with an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cot

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible with a toolbar. A toolbar's `box` layout always has all items aligned in one direction (top and bottom toolbars horizontally, left and right toolbars vertically), and it is not supported to apply a different layout to a toolbar.

You can, however, equip your toolbar with arrows that allow you to scroll, or with a menu that takes all items that don't fit on the screen. The required configuration is [`overflowHandler:'scroller'` or `overflowHandler:'menu'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar.html#cfg-overflowHandler), respectively.

Comment: Not working,these both configs are not presented in Extjs 3.2.

Comment: Not my fault, you didn't specify that you use such an old version.